# PowerShell extract folder content from zip

Tags: powershell

I have multiple folders, let's say they are `Folder1, Folder2, Folder3, etc.` Inside everyone of them there is `.zip` file named like the folder name. So `Folder1.zip, Folder2.zip, Folder3.zip, etc.` Inside every zip there is `path` like `Content/1/a/5/t/ZIPNAME/a/b/c/temp`. The path is the same except where `ZIPNAME` is the zip currently iterating. `temp` folder has the files I need to copy to newly created folder like the `.zip` name. How can I achive that?

This is what I got at the moment. Iterating over every folder, getting the zip and opening it. How to get the content from the zip file and copy it to new folder?

```
    Set-Location -Path $(BaseDeployPath)
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
          $zipPath = Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Filter *.zip
          $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipPath)

          $contentPath = ???

          $zip.Entries | Get-Content $contentPath
    }

    # close ZIP file
    $zip.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the documentation. The [`OpenRead()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.openread) method returns a [`ZipArchive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive) object, whose [`Entries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.entries) property holds a collection of [`ZipArchiveEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry) objects. These objects have (among other things) a property `FullName` with the relative path of the item inside the archive, hence you should be able to select the file you want to process like this:

```
$temp = 'Content/1/a/5/t/ZIPNAME/a/b/c/temp/'

$zip = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipPath)
$entries = $zip.Entries | Where-Object { $_.FullName.StartsWith($temp) -and $_.Name }
```

The additional clause `-and $_.Name` excludes directory entries (which have an empty `Name` property) from the result.

The documentation also lists a method `ExtractToFile()` which supposedly allows extracting entries to files. However, that method wasn't available on my testbox. Not sure whether it's just not available in PowerShell or if it was added in a more recent version of the .Net framework.

You can extract files the old-fashioned way, though:

```
$entries | ForEach-Object {
    $dstPath = Join-Path 'C:\destination\folder' $_.Name

    $src = $_.Open()
    $dst = New-Object IO.FileStream $dstPath, 'Create', 'Write', 'Read'
    $src.CopyTo($dst)
    $src.Close(); $src.Dispose()
    $dst.Close(); $dst.Dispose()
}
```